# Booking 1 day late to cancel what will happen?

Tags: cancellations, booking.com

I miscalculated the days i have to cancel the trip and now when I was canceling it said something about 150$ cancellation fee. I'm not quite sure was it a booking linked to some of my cards, what do you think ? what will happen will I get charged if I have money on my card ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't cancel you'll be charged the full amount. If you do cancel you'll be charged the cancellation fee, which looks like $150.

Those would appear to be the contract terms. If you have no funds in your card they may come after you some other way.

Comment: I contacted the Hotel and they gave me free cancellation I'm rly grateful to them, so If anyone has the same problem he should write to the hotel directly because it's up to them to forgive you